# Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin/auth'

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, firebase-cli

I'm getting the following error while trying to deploy any function to firebase functions:

Command:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

And this is the output

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin/auth'
```

I've already tried removing node_modules folder with `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` with no success.

Firebase tools version: 11.18.0
Node version: v18.12.1
NPM version: 8.19.2

It was properly working only few days ago and suddenly stopped. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you use `await` top-level and query firestore data? If so, you can remove or use an other approach.